# Matlab: pointwise function command?

Tags: matlab

Is there a method in Matlab on transforming a function to a pointwise function? For example if the input is a function x^2, then I want the output to be x.^2

Comment: have a look at at `bsxfun`: [doc](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) - there is also an example for custom functions.

Comment: and then there's also `arrayfun`, `cellfun`, etc.

Comment: I assume you have a few lines of code that need fixing. If you really want to change the operator function it may technically be possible by overloading, but believe me: you won't want that for these basic functions.

Comment: I'm building a GUI in Matlab, where one of the things the user can do, is write a function in a textfield. Now, behind the 'scenes', I want to transform this function to a pointwise function (for later use in the GUI).

Comment: Thx. Well, I guess you could do something along the lines of Dennis Jaheruddin's answer, but where he proposed to search and replace in the editor, you search and replace in you input string. see `strrep`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though it is really not a solution, but a trick that sometimes works. Here is what you can do if your script is trival enough:

Use `ctrl+h` to replace

```
^ by .^
* by .*
```

And then replace

```
..^ by .^
..* by .*
```

And so on, you can continue with the operators that you want to adjust. Of course there are also functions like `mtimes` that would need to be adjusted, but if you are lucky you didn't use them.